# Can't see my widget name in admin dropdown

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, widgets

I am learning about widgets through this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1). I have done everything as mentioned in that link but still I can't see my widget in admin panel..

I observed some error logs in var/log/system.log file which are as follows:

> 2013-10-03T06:56:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 510
>   2013-10-03T06:56:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:  <?xml version="1.0"?>  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 510
>   2013-10-03T06:56:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:       ^  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 510

The above log lines are repeated many times.

As instructed, I am trying to see my widget in :

```
CMS > Pages > select "home" > go to "content" tab > press "insert widget" in WYSIWYG editor.
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a paste of your code (please add one) I would guess reading the error that there is a foreign character or more likely whitespace at the top of your XML document.

That is ultimately what the message means, you can only have the XML declaration, i.e. `<?xml version="1.0">` or whatever at the start of your .xml file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The XML parsing in PHP is very strict.

The piece of error from the above log is saying :

> `XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`

So, it is stating clearly that the xml declaration is not present at the very start of the xml file. So, I looked in my newly added xml files and found **space** just before the xml declaration.

When I removed that space, the newly added widgets were visible in admin panel.

Thanks to XB23 (*user on IRC*).